# Angular 2 calling API with Basic Security Authorization

Tags: typescript, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-services, angular2-http

I'm trying to call an HTTP method implmented with ASP Web API from an Angular 2 client.
And I'm getting this error:

> OPTIONS http://endpoint/api/Get?key=something 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://endpoint/api/Get?key=something. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Here is my implementation, which works well when I disable the basic authentication on the IIS Server:

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Entity } from "app/view-models/entity";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    headers;
    options;
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));
        this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        this.options = new RequestOptions();
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: new Headers(this.headers) });
    }

    public Get = (): Observable<Entity> => {
        var params = '?key=something';
        return this._http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + environment.getSettings + params
            , this.options)
            .map(response => <Entity>response.json());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Maybe you solved in The end? Same problem here

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a CORS error than an angular/typescript error.  You're trying to cross from "localhost" to "endpoint".  You have to configure your endpoint service to allow requests from this domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: It is already done in the WebApiConfig this way: var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute( origins: "", headers: "", methods: "*"); config.EnableCors(cors); 
And as I mentionned when when I disable the basic authentication on the IIS it works well.